# ons-lazy-repeat refresh() not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, onsen-ui, onsen-ui2

I have a working onsen lazy repeat list that I creating using this code:

HTML:

```
<ons-page ng-controller="LazyListController as list" ng-init="init(homeNavigator.topPage.data.wordlistId)">
  <ons-toolbar>
    <div class="left">
      <ons-back-button>Back</ons-back-button>
    </div>
    <div class="center">{{ homeNavigator.topPage.data.title }}</div>
  </ons-toolbar>

<ons-list>
  <ons-list-item class="list-item-container" ons-lazy-repeat="MyDelegate" id="lazy_list">
  </ons-list-item>
</ons-list>
</ons-page>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['onsen', 'ngCordova']);
  app.controller('LazyListController', function ($scope, $window, $document, $cordovaCamera) {

$scope.MyDelegate = {
  configureItemScope: function (index, itemScope) {

   ... 


  },
  countItems: function () {
    return $scope.wordsInList != undefined ? $scope.wordsInList.length : 0;
  },
  calculateItemHeight: function () {
    return ons.platform.isAndroid() ? 100 : 100;
  }
};

updateEditList = function (wordlistId) {

  ...
    $scope.MyDelegate.refresh();
  ...

});
```

However when I later call `$scope.MyDelegate.refresh();`I get the error that refresh is not a function. I'm not sure how to call the refresh method!

Comment: There is no refresh method to call in your code!

Comment: how does this work then? https://onsen.io/v2/docs/angular1/ons-lazy-repeat.html

Comment: Can you post the rest of the JS?

Comment: sure! I had to remove some parts

Comment: You seem to be missing the ons.bootstrap() line? Or maybe you have it somewhere else?

Comment: I did remove that and used the angular.module line as shown. Would that be a problem?

Comment: I changed it to ons.bootstrap and it didn't make any difference